# Why the alignment and stride of empty struct are 1?

Tags: swift, memory-layout

Consider the following:

```
struct Empty {}

MemoryLayout<Empty>.size        // 0
MemoryLayout<Empty>.stride      // 1
MemoryLayout<Empty>.alignment   // 1
```

Based on what I understand about [MemoryLayout](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/memorylayout) properties, it is expected that the size is 0. However:

- the `alignment` should be the maximum size for `Empty` properties.
- the `stride` should be the number of bytes to shift the point for reaching the next memory location.

In this case, there are no even declared properties in `Empty` (`Empty` has `size` of 0), so how it has `alignment` of 1 and `stride` of 1?

Comment: From https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/ABI/TypeLayout.rst: *"Start with a size of 0 and an **alignment of 1**"*

Comment: From https://www.raywenderlich.com/148569/unsafe-swift: This is because each EmptyStruct that you create has to have a unique memory address despite being of zero size.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for the useful links. "This is because each EmptyStruct that you create has to have a unique memory address despite being of zero size", I'm unsure that I understood it right 